# Is it best to use Node.js or SignalR

Tags: node.js, signalr

At the risk of this question being closed I will ask anyway.

I have been looking at the different JavaScript Frameworks as most jobs roles seem to want:
angular.js
Knockout.js
Node.js

Whilst i can see Angualr.js and Knockout.js provides a MVC construct to the markup pages (though still not sure which one is best to use) I cannot see what is the case for node.js?

Whilst I appreciate node.js is good for real-time comms but so is Signalr as they both use long-polling.

At present I use signalr to update images on my clients.

is there any purpose to swapping this out for node.js?

Like I said this question could be voted to be closed as it may seem to be asking an opinion - and that would be an answer to me in itself as it would be down to developer choice but is there a DEFINITIVE reason to use node.js over signalr?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason to use node.js is code redundancy. Both the server and client run the same language, thus they may share a certain part of the codebase, meaning potentially less to write. With libraries like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) this process can be made a lot more transparent and writing the client-side can be almost indistinguishable from server-side development. Another opportunity this opens up is both client and server side rendering + MVC setups with, for example, [rendr.js](https://github.com/rendrjs/rendr). So you can have both the fast load speeds of server-side and responsiveness of client-side rendering. If any of this will be useful naturally depends on what you are developing.

Comment: seems good and reasonable points. Thanks

Comment: It has been a while since I looked at my project.  Forgive my cheeky question but you seem to know what you are talking about. At present I have a MVC app that uses signalr to push jpegs to my client which are then rendered onto my canvas control.  I am always looking at ways to quicken this process as I showing a live feed from my webcam. Can node.js and that render.js be used for this purpose instead and would it be quicker do you think? :)

Comment: Pushing JPEGs to a canvas is very inefficient. You should rather stream a video to the client. This can be done with a native HTML5 video format like  WebM, OGG or MP4, WebM being optimal, if you don't care about IE and other outdated browsers, otherwise MP4. The most direct approach is piping the output of ffmpeg directly to the client. Can't really find a good example, so you can use this [MP3 streaming server](https://github.com/bakape/livestreamer-mp3) as a makeshift guide.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  This roject has to use MJPEG for various reasons..

Comment: but thanks for the link :)